# Best way to introduce B-splines?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, polynomials, approximation-theory, fourier-transform, splines

I have the option of mentoring pure math undergrads in a topic lying within Approximation Theory and I really want to do $B$-splines. Mostly because I have recently found applications of them in my own research and I think it's a good opportunity for me to further learn the material. (And to show them cool stuff as well of course.)

Suppose we are given a sequence of knots **t** $= (t_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} \subset \mathbb{R}$.
I am aware of two ways in which $B$-splines can be defined.

**Method 1:** First define the $B$-splines of order $1$ (or degree $0$) to be the characteristic functions $B_{i1} = \chi_{[t_i,t_{i+1})}$. Then we define the $B$-splines of higher order by the recurrence relation

$$B_{ik} =  \lambda_{ik}B_{i,k-1} + (1 - \lambda_{i+1,k})B_{i+1,k-1}$$
where
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{ik}(t) =  \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{t - t_i}{t_{i+k-1} - t_i} &  \quad  \text{if} \ \ \ t_i \neq t_{i+k-1} \\
            0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

I understand that this is a computationally practical way of defining $B$-splines and that many of the early theorems about $B$-splines have simple proof when given this definition. However, I am of the opinion that you wouldn't introduce $B$-splines this way unless you really want to bore your audience as this recurrence relation is highly unmotivated and, until you begin to actually prove theorems with it, it simply doesn't look interesting.

The next way is longer but the idea is more natural (at first at least). I don't want to make this post too long so I will skip details. I include some details for completion, but I suspect someone with an answer to this post is likely familiar with everything I mention below.

**Method 2:** Suppose we are investigating the problem of finding a basis for the space of piece-wise polynomials of order $k$ (or degree $k-1$) with breakpoints at $(t_i)$ with some specified smoothness condition at each $t_i$. To find this basis we first make the problem easier by finding a basis for the space of piece-wise polynomials on $\mathbb{R}$ with a **finite** set of breakpoints and some specified smoothness condition at these breakpoints. If this finite knot sequence is $\{x_1, \dots x_n\} $, we get led to the **truncated power basis** $\{(t - x_i)_+^{j} | 1 \leq i \leq n , 0 \leq j \leq k-1\}$.

We then find some linear combination of these truncated powers to begin constructing compactly supported piece-wise polynomials supported on closed intervals with end points belonging to our knot sequence **t**. (I have skipped many details here). But in order to actually define the $B$-splines, we need to find out the coefficients of the truncated powers that yield them. This takes us to the **divided difference** operators and I am not a fan of these operators either. I also find considering them to be somewhat unmotivated (albeit not as unmotivated as the first idea).

**My question:** Are there other ways to introduce $B$-splines aside from the $2$ methods I have given?

I suspect the solution to my dilemna is to understand these divided difference operators more in depth, but I want to know if there are other ways. I've been reading through a book on **Box Splines** which are defined as distributions. It seems interesting, but I've only begun and don't yet fully see how they generalize $B$-splines. Even if this approach would work as well, I am unsure whether it would be accessible to undergrads.

Comment: I've always rather liked the "Pyramid Algorithms" approach to this stuff advocated by e.g. Ron Goldman. The Hermite-Genocchi/Kergin approach you mention leads to lots of interesting mathematics, but isn't something I think I'd have been able to appreciate fully as an undergraduate (though maybe that's not saying all that much!)

Comment: One issue with approach #2 is that the goal of "finding a basis" of something is a very abstract motivation for undergraduates. On the other hand, finding a way to draw smooth curves given control points is concrete, and something they may have seen in drawing programs. What about starting with the natural motivation of drawing curves, show some simple example cases, and then introduce (as a kind of "aha!" moment) the idea that a linear algebra approach can organize and clarify the problem? Using plenty of diagrams will obviously help, too.

Comment: @MartinM.W.  I think whether it's abstract depends on the audience. These are pure math undergrads I'll be working with who have taken undergrad analysis and algebra. My research is in approximation theory so my idea was to introduce to them the approximation properties of splines. I am actually somewhat unfamiliar with this "drawing curves" thing you mention so I'll do some reading about it.

Answer (score 3):

The undergrad course I took which included B-splines spent a lot of time first on Bézier curves. You might not necessarily want to spend much time on them, but I think they can motivate a variant on method 1 by defining Bézier curves with de Casteljau's algorithm and B-spline curves with de Boor's algorithm. This assumes that you're at least as interested in the curves as in the basis functions, but since you talk about applications...

Note that I haven't tested this on anyone (undergrad or no) and the latter half has somewhat the flavour of experimental mathematics, which may not suit your pedagogical style.

#### Basics

We start from the concept of a spline curve as a curve defined by some control points and weighting functions, and we parameterise the weighting functions over an interval of the real line. So generically we have $P(t) = \sum_k w_k(t) P_t$ where $w_k$ is the $k$th weighting function and $P_k$ is the $k$th control point. One highly desirable property of the weighting functions is that for all $t$ in the interval on which the line is defined, $\sum_k w_k(t) = 1$, because this is necessary and sufficient for an affine transformation of the control points to transform the entire line consistently.

#### Recursive interpolation

A straightforward way to achieve this unit weight property is to choose weighting functions corresponding to recursive interpolation. In other words, the evaluation process is to define a series of sequences of control points starting with the original control points ($P_{0,k} = P_k$) and repeatedly interpolating between adjacent control points, reducing the number of points by one each time, until we get down to a single point. In general, $$P_{i,k} = (1 - f_{i,k}(t)) P_{i-1,k} + f_{i,k}(t) P_{i-1,k+1}$$

(This may be a good point at which to show that if the $f_{i,k}$ all map into $[0,1]$ then we get the convex hull property).

#### Example 1: Bézier

The simplest such scheme is to take $[0,1]$ as our interval of the real line and $f_{i,k}(t) = t$. Then by induction we can show that the corresponding weighting functions are $w_k(t) = \binom{n}{k} (1-t)^{n-k} t^k$ when we have $n+1$ control points numbered $P_0$ to $P_n$. This is the Bézier spline, which is very popular but has some important drawbacks. In particular, we can see that each weighting function has support over the entirety of $(0,1)$. We can attempt to fix this and achieve local control by chaining a series of Bézier curves, which we now treat as segments in a larger curve. For simple continuity we require the last control point of one segment to be the first control point of the next segment; if we want higher level continuity then we impose conditions on more control points. (There's an elegant umbral calculus approach to Bézier curves as $P(t) = (1 - t + t \mathcal{P})^n$ where $\mathcal{P}^k$ corresponds to $P_k$ which allows us to derive the condition for $c$th order continuity from segment $P$ to subsequent segment $Q$ as $$\forall j \le c: Q_j = 2^j \sum_{k=0}^j (-2)^k \binom{j}{k} P_{n-k}$$
so that if we want a degree of continuity at the joins which is half of the degree of the segments then moving a control point in one segment can have knock-on effects beyond the adjacent segment; but I suspect that this level of detail is too much of a digression for you. It's more straightforward to show that the $c$th derivative of segment $P$ at $P_n$ depends on the last $c+1$ control points in the segment, and similarly the $c$th derivative of segment $Q$ at $Q_0$ depends on the first $c+1$ control points, so that equating them necessarily establishes constraints between those control points).

#### Example 2: cardinal B-spline

A natural solution is to say that if we're going to have constraints between the control points which directly affect adjacent segments of our curve, we should take the simplest possible constraints: identification. Therefore we'll have a single set of control points $P_k$ and we'll say that for $t \in [a, a+1)$ we'll perform a recursive interpolation involving points $P_a$ to $P_{a+n}$. (This may not be the standard indexing, for which I apologise). Still in the interests of simplicity, we'll take the $f_{i,k}$ as linear functions: $f_{i,k}(t) = \alpha_{i,k} t + \beta_{i,k}$. And in the interests of uniformity we'll refine the interpolation to take into account that we're handling multiple segments, and update it to $$P_{i,k} = (1 - f_{i,k}(t-a)) P_{i-1,k} + f_{i,k}(t-a) P_{i-1,k+1}$$

Then the question is what values of $\alpha_{i,k}$ and $\beta_{i,k}$ maximise the continuity between the segments without imposing constraints between the $P_k$.

In $[a, a+1)$ we have (introducing some hopefully transparent notation for brevity)

- $P_{0,k} = P_{a+k}$ for $0 \le k \le n$.
- $P_{1,k} = \overline{f_{1,k}} P_{a+k} + f_{1,k} P_{a+k+1}$ for $0 \le k \le n-1$.
- $P_{2,k} = \overline{f_{1,k}} \overline{f_{2,k}} P_{a+k} + (f_{1,k} \overline{f_{2,k}} + \overline{f_{1,k+1}} f_{2,k}) P_{a+k+1} + f_{1,k+1} f_{2,k} P_{a+k+2}$ for $0 \le k \le n-2$

etc.

In the interests of having a digestible example, consider the case $n=2$.

$P(t) = P_{n,0} = \overline{f_{1,0}} \overline{f_{2,0}} P_{a} + (f_{1,0} \overline{f_{2,0}} + \overline{f_{1,1}} f_{2,0}) P_{a+1} + f_{1,1} f_{2,0} P_{a+2}$

In the segment $[a, a+1)$,
$$\lim_{t \to a+1} P(t) = \overline{f_{1,0}} \overline{f_{2,0}} (1) P_{a} + (f_{1,0} \overline{f_{2,0}} + \overline{f_{1,1}} f_{2,0}) (1) P_{a+1} + f_{1,1} f_{2,0} (1) P_{a+2}$$ and in the segment $[a+1, a+2)$ we have
$$P(a+1) = \overline{f_{1,0}} \overline{f_{2,0}} (0) P_{a+1} + (f_{1,0} \overline{f_{2,0}} + \overline{f_{1,1}} f_{2,0}) (0) P_{a+2} + f_{1,1} f_{2,0} (0) P_{a+3}$$
So for simple continuity without imposing constraints on the control points we require

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(1 - \alpha_{1,0} - \beta_{1,0})(1 - \alpha_{2,0} - \beta_{2,0}) &=& 0 \\
(\alpha_{1,0} + \beta_{1,0}) (1 - \alpha_{2,0} - \beta_{2,0}) + (1 - \alpha_{1,1} - \beta_{1,1}) (\alpha_{2,0} + \beta_{2,0}) &=& (1 - \beta_{1,0})(1 - \beta_{2,0}) \\
\alpha_{1,1} \alpha_{2,0} + \alpha_{1,1} \beta_{2,0} + \alpha_{2,0} \beta_{1,1} &=& \beta_{1,0} - \beta_{1,0} \beta_{2,0} + \beta_{2,0} \\
0 &=& \beta_{1,1} \beta_{2,0}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

This still leaves some degrees of freedom, so we can consider continuity of the first derivative, which (some algebra-bashing omitted) yields

\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha_{1,0}(1 - 2 \alpha_{2,0} - \beta_{2,0}) + \alpha_{2,0} (1 - \beta_{1,0}) &=& 0 \\
\alpha_{1,0} (2 - 2 \alpha_{2,0} - 2 \beta_{2,0}) - \alpha_{1,1} (2 \alpha_{2,0} + \beta_{2,0}) + \alpha_{2,0} (2 - 2 \beta_{1,0} - \beta_{1,1}) &=& 0 \\
\alpha_{1,0} (1 - \beta_{2,0}) - \alpha_{1,1} (2 \alpha_{2,0} + 2 \beta_{2,0}) + \alpha_{2,0} (1 - \beta_{1,0} - 2 \beta_{1,1}) &=& 0 \\
\alpha_{1,1} \beta_{2,0} + \alpha_{2,0} \beta_{1,1} &=& 0
\end{eqnarray*}

and combining the two sets of continuity constraints we get $\alpha_{1,0} = \tfrac12$, $\alpha_{1,1} = \tfrac12$, $\alpha_{2,0} = 1$, $\beta_{1,0} = \tfrac12$, $\beta_{1,1} = 0$, $\beta_{2,0} = 0$.

If we now suggest considering $\alpha_{i,k} = \frac1{n+1-i}$, $\beta_{i,k} = \frac{n-k-i}{n+1-i}$ then it's no longer *entirely* unmotivated...

#### The full B-spline

Thus far we haven't mentioned knots, but there's no fundamental reason why we should segment the parameter space at the integers...

Once the full generality has been introduced, and since we came via Bézier curves, it's probably worth throwing out a comment about the Bézier basis functions corresponding to B-spline basis functions with knot vectors $0^u 1^v$.